# How to add a timeout to an asynchronous FtpWebRequest

Tags: xamarin.ios, ftpwebrequest

I have the following code that works fine for sending a file by FTP, but it blocks my UI.

```
 FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ftpUrl + filename);
            request.UsePassive = false;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUser, ftpPass);
            request.Timeout = 10000; //10 second timeout

            byte[] fileContents = File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);
            request.ContentLength = fileContents.Length;
            //Stream requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);

            requestStream.Close();
```

I want to switch the Stream to the commented line so I call asynchronously and don't block my UI, and it works fine, except for the timeout, which according to the docs is for synchronous use only.

The question is how to make a timeout work on an async call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From document [FtpWebRequest.Timeout Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.timeout?view=netframework-4.8) ,Timeout is the number of milliseconds that a synchronous request made with the GetResponse method waits for a response and that the GetRequestStream method waits for a stream. So there is no more api to use it asynchronously .

Maybe this can be a good way to realize it.Putting **FtpWebRequest** code into the Task to have a try.

```
// Start a new task (this launches a new thread)
Task.Factory.StartNew (() => {
    // Do some work on a background thread, allowing the UI to remain responsive
    DoSomething();
// When the background work is done, continue with this code block
}).ContinueWith (task => {
    DoSomethingOnTheUIThread();
// the following forces the code in the ContinueWith block to be run on the
// calling thread, often the Main/UI thread.
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext ());
```

Comment: I had already tried running the FtpWebRequest in its own thread, but it did not seem like the Timeout was working even with the synchronous method. However, having tried it again it did work, I was just deliberately blocking the network connection to simulate poor conditions. I might be wrong but it seems to me that the Timeout only fires after the credentials have been accepted. If you're in a situation where the client is unable to make any contact the Timeout doesn't seem to apply. Either way, running the synchronous method in a separate thread is the way to go.

Comment: @PhilJohn Yeah, Timeout doesn't trigger when there is no connection, I think this is its current limit.